# Profiles saving on MAGMI does not work

Tags: magento

I have installed MAGMI and UI looks ok. But it does not allowing me to save any profile. The messge "no profile saved yet" still on. Pressing save profile does not change a thing. Please help. 
I am using Magento 1.9 with Magmi 0.7.19a

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328185/magmi-errors-no-profile-saved-yet-run-disabled/