# Magmi errors “No Profile saved yet, Run disabled!!”

Tags: magmi

I have a brand new install of Magmi (v0.7.22), I have created a profile, I get the following error

> No Profile saved yet, Run disabled!!

on another note the updater gives me this error Upgrade/Upload function are disabled for security reasons

I am with Nexcess if this provides any clues

Comment: Hi Justin. This question is off topic for Stackoverflow. You *might* get some help on the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), however I'm not sure that Magmi would be on topic there either.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, I hope following snap will help you.

[image]

First fill your global details and then use Copy Profile and save.

Answer (score 0):

Using Magmi version 7.21 worked, by default you download 7.22. This is correct answer as it solved the issue and I am now able to run magmi

Kausal Suchar, that wasn't my issue, i did create a profile, thank you for responding

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=UI_Main_page_organization

You have to save profile first.

The save profile button is present at the bottom-right corner.

See the sample image below:

[image]